# How include an array of structure in a structure and edit it in a function

Tags: struct, solidity, smartcontracts

I train myself to solidity and write some smart contracts to fill my github with projects.
My current project involves a user sending ETH into the smart contract in exchange for a code. This same user (or another) can then enter this code in an input, validate and he will receive the ETH corresponding to the creator's code.
That's the context of the project.

---

For store users's codes I created a `struct Code` and a `struct UserCode` :

```
struct Code {
    uint256 code;
    uint256 value;
}

struct UserCode {
    address userAddress;
    Code[] codes;
}

UserCode[] private userCodes;
```

Like this, one user can have severals codes, I can display for user his codes in the dApp, etc ...
But when I try to push datas in `userCodes`, I don't know what's the way to do that.

I try this :

```
function createCode() public payable {
    UserCode memory newDeposit;
    Code[] memory newCode;
    newCode.push([Code(
        getRandom(),     /// A function I create before to return a pseudo random uint256
        msg.value
    )]);
    newDeposit.userAddress = msg.sender;
    newDeposit.codes.push(newCode);

    userCodes.push(newDeposit);
```

But doesn't work because I have an error like I can't use `push()` method because `newCode` is memory.
I also try to not declare `newCode` as an array of struct :

```
function createCode() public payable {
    UserCode memory newDeposit;
    Code memory newCode;
    newCode.code = getRandom();
    newCode.value = msg.value;
    newDeposit.userAddress = msg.sender;
    newDeposit.codes.push(newCode);

    userCodes.push(newDeposit);
```

Same error and another like in **UserCode struct**, `codes`is an array of `struct Code` and here, I push just a `Code`variable.

After that I change my strategy and used **mapping** like this :

```
struct Code {
    uint256 code;
    uint256 value;
}

mapping(address => Code[]) private userCodes;
```

It works perfect, i change ma `createCode()`function like this :

```
/**
 * @notice Assigns a code corresponding to the value sent by the user. And stores them in the "userCodes" mapping.
 */
function createCode() public payable {
    /// Push the new code with its value in the mapping
    userCodes[msg.sender].push(
        Code(
            getRandom(), /// To generate a random code (cf. getRandom() function)
            msg.value
        ));
    }
```

But when I try to make a function `redeemCode(uint256 code)`. I can't browse the mapping to see if the code exists ...

---

So my conclusion is that I think I have to use an array of structure in my structure `UserCode` but I don't know how I can add my datas in.

I hope I was clear, thank you so mush for your help.

v4ss.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've made some progress in your Solidity project, and you've switched to using a mapping to store user codes, which is a good approach for your use case. To check if a code exists in the mapping and redeem it, you can create a function like this:

```
/**
 * @notice Redeems a code and transfers the corresponding ETH value to the sender.
 * @param code The code to redeem.
 */
function redeemCode(uint256 code) public {
    // Get the array of codes for the sender
    Code[] storage codes = userCodes[msg.sender];

    // Iterate through the user's codes to find a matching one
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        if (codes[i].code == code) {
            // Found a matching code, transfer the ETH value to the sender
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(codes[i].value);

            // Remove the redeemed code from the array (optional)
            if (i < codes.length - 1) {
                // Move the last code in the array to the position of the redeemed code
                codes[i] = codes[codes.length - 1];
            }
            // Reduce the length of the array to remove the last element
            codes.pop();
            
            // Exit the loop once the code is redeemed
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This **redeemCode** function allows a user to redeem their code by providing the code they want to redeem. It checks if the provided code exists in the user's array of codes and transfers the corresponding ETH value to the sender. If the code is found, it is removed from the array (optional).

Comment: Thank you Ricardo for your help, I appreciate !
The problem here is that only the creator of the code can redeem its value. In my use case, I wanted that if I send 2 ETH into the smart contract in exchange for a code, if I give you the code, you will also be able to use it to redeem the value. (Like a gift card, if you see what I mean). That's why, I said the mapping didn't allow me to navigate in it to find if the code existed.